# Rendering plots with Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I was curious how I could render a picture like the one I included. [image]

I apologize if this is a newbie question, however I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to mimic something like this with tikz.

Comment: Welcome! It is straightforward, in particular if one knows the functions. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is to give you a start. The `x` positions of the interval boundaries are stored in a list.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.4+0.2*sin(\x*120)+0.05*\x;}]
 \def\mylist{0,3,4.5,5.75,7.5}
 \draw[dashed]foreach \X in \mylist { (\X,-0.2) -- (\X,2)};
 \draw plot[domain={{\mylist}[0]}:{{\mylist}[1]},smooth] 
    (\x,{f(\x)});
 \draw plot[domain={{\mylist}[1]}:{{\mylist}[2]},smooth] 
    (\x,{0.7-1/(\x-{\mylist}[3])});
 \draw plot[domain={{\mylist}[2]}:{{\mylist}[3]},smooth] 
    (\x,{0.6*(\x-{\mylist}[2])+0.6});
 \draw plot[domain={{\mylist}[3]}:{{\mylist}[4]},smooth] 
    (\x,{-0.2*pow(\x-({\mylist}[3]+{\mylist}[4])/2,2)+0.5});
 \draw plot[domain={{\mylist}[0]-1}:{{\mylist}[0]},smooth] 
    (\x,{-0.2*pow(\x-(2*{\mylist}[0]-1)/2,2)+1});
 \draw ({min(\mylist)-2},0) -- ({max(\mylist)+1},0);
 \draw[red,stealth-] ({{\mylist}[0]},{f({\mylist}[0])}) -- ++ (-1,0.25)
  node[left]{$v^+_{j-\frac{1}{2}}$};
 \draw[red,stealth-] ({{\mylist}[1]},{f({\mylist}[1])}) -- ++ (-1,1)
  node[above left]{$v^-_{j+\frac{1}{2}}$};
 \path ({{\mylist}[0]},-0.2) node[below]{$x_{j-\frac{1}{2}}$}
    ({{\mylist}[1]},-0.2) node[below]{$x_{j+\frac{1}{2}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]